# Is there a way in Javascript to select elements matching a boolean expression of multiple class names?

Tags: javascript, html

Say I have multiple elements on a page and each element has one or more class names, e.g.:

```
<div class="A1 A2 B1">…</div>
<div class="A2 C3">…</div>
<div class="B2 C3">…</div>
etc.
```

Is there a way to select, for example, all elements that have

```
class = (A1 OR A2) AND (B1 OR B2)
```

?

Comment: Aside from writing a custom lookup, you can't do that out of the box. However, CSS selectors can sort of cover that, as long as your selection logic is not too complex. The boolean expression you have resolves in four branches, so you can just have four selectors.

Comment: Thanks, Olian. I guess this makes the challenge building the proper selector string based on user checkbox input -- but if have trouble there it will be a new question. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use css selectors with the `querySelectorAll` function.

`(A1 OR A2) AND (B1 OR B2)` is the same as saying `(A1 AND B1) OR (A1 AND B2) OR (A2 AND B1) OR (A2 AND B2)` which we can express using css selectors like this `.A1.B1, .A1.B2, .A2.B1, .A2.B2`.

```js
// (A1 OR A2) AND (B1 OR B2)
const selector = '.A1.B1, .A1.B2, .A2.B1, .A2.B2';

const $elems = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

$elems.forEach($el => console.log($el));
```

```html
<div class="A1 A2 B1"></div>
<div class="A1 B1"></div>
<div class="A1 B2"></div>
<div class="A2 B1"></div>
<div class="A2 B2"></div>
<div class="A2 C3"></div>
<div class="B2 C3"></div>
```

- More on CSS selectors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors
- More on querySelectorAll: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: For more expressivity, you could also use [`:is(.A1, .A2):is(.B1, .B2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is)

Comment: @Bergi that is true. However the [browser compatibility for `:is`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is#Browser_compatibility) is a bit flaky.